# Conversion to float limits the returned result to only 7 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point

I have a query which parses a string and converts it to float and then adds the result up.

This is the code:

```
[XXX]      = (SELECT CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),0,3))AS float) + (CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),3,6))AS float)/60))
```

if I highlight the the select all the way down to the end this is the result

**13.9503166666667**

but when i use the whole code which is like:

```
INSERT INTO TblCurrent_TEMP(XXX)
SELECT [XXX]      = (SELECT CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),0,3))AS float) + (CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),3,6))AS float)/60))
```

this returns like this.

**13.9503**

i expected the results like this

**13.950316**

is there something wrong with my query

my table structure is

**XXX varchar(500)**

Comment: any specific reason why you want to save it back as `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [STR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function

> Returns character data converted from numeric data.

So something like

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        XXX VARCHAR(500)
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (XXX)
SELECT XXX = LTRIM(STR((SELECT CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),0,3))AS float) + (CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),3,6))AS float)/60)), 500, 10))

SELECT  *
FROM    @TABLE
```

From [CAST and Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) You will notice that the conversion from FLOAT to `VARCHAR` is implicit and that there is a section mentioning **Truncating and Rounding Results**

Also, have a loot at the below results

```
SELECT  CAST(CAST(5.5 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.55 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.555 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.5555 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.55555 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.555555 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.5555555 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(CAST(5.55555555 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(10))

SELECT  STR(CAST(5.5 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.55 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.555 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.5555 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.55555 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.555555 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.5555555 AS FLOAT),10,10),
        STR(CAST(5.55555555 AS FLOAT),10,10)
```

*You should probably store the value in a more appropriate type, unless this is an attribute table which is suppose to store multiple types.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
  Change datatype of xxx to numeric(10,6)

```
    create table TblCurrent_TEMP
    (
        XXX numeric(10,6)
    )

    insert into TblCurrent_TEMP
    select (SELECT CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),0,3))AS float) + (CAST((SUBSTRING (SUBSTRING('351856040522039,241111;1G,150403155719,A,1357.0198N,12136.8786E,0.0,345,1.0,01004000;', 42, 9),3,6))AS float)/60))


     select * from TblCurrent_TEMP
```